# Extract values in a Spatial Polygon dataframe

Tags: r, extract, polygon

I'm currently trying to find out a value of a certain polygon in my Spatial Polygon dataframe. I need to know what "ID" was assigned to each "FSA" level. Below is the picture of how my data is set up. The dataset is called "FSA2015EditedFINAL2". I tried this:

```
FSA2015EditedFINAL2@polygons[[1]]@ID
```

But that just tells me the first polygons ID, and I don't know what FSA that corresponds to...

I'm hoping to be able to type in the FSA I need and pull out what ID it got.

Any help would be amazing!!!!

Thanks!

[image: Global Environment]

Comment: Have you tried `sapply(FSA2015EditedFINAL2@polygons, function(x) x@ID)`?

Comment: @AllanCameron EPIC! That's way closer to what I want! It gave me a list of all the ID's in order! I still don't know which FSA the ID is though :S

Comment: Holly, why not take those IDs and put them in your data frame like `FSA2015EditedFINAL2$ID <- sapply(FSA2015EditedFINAL2@polygons, function(x) x@ID)` That way, you can get the FSA by `FSA2015EditedFINAL2$FSA[FSA2015EditedFINAL2$ID == "ID goes here"]`. Of course, this would be a lot easier if your dataframe was called `df`!